# Getting started with Yeoman and Backbone

Tags: backbone.js, web, requirejs, marionette, yeoman

I would like to use Yeoman and build a Backbone + Marionette + RequireJS project.
What are the things to consider and what are the actual commands I should run inorder to get things up and running.

Comment: Installed Yeoman with grunt and bower (npm install -g yo grunt-cli bower) ... I did look at the getting started guide, and did not found any backbone related instructions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently yeoman doesn't have official marionette generator - [issue](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/issues/404).

But you can try to modify [Backbone.js generator](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-backbone) for your needs.

Also you can check [Yeoman generator for Express, Marionette and Backbone with AMD](https://github.com/mrichard/generator-marionette)

Answer (score 2):

There is a backend agnostic yeoman generator for the client aspect of a Backbone Marionette app called [generator-maryo](https://github.com/simonblee/generator-maryo).